# APACHE POI - Removing duplicate values from hundreds of previous excel files

Tags: java, excel, algorithm, arraylist, apache-poi

My company calls customers and offers them to buy things. Every month we get 20 new excel files ,each including thousands of phone numbers and he has a staff calling them.

The problem is that sometimes n "new" excel file he recieves contains phone-numbers which already existed in one of the excel files he got a few months ealier. so that the customers were annoyed that they were being called again.

He asked me if i could help him out somehow. So I thought I would build a program which saves all phones in a text file named STORED.txt:

It has 2 cases:

1.if STORED.txt is empty:
Add each phone of the excel file to STORED.txt.

2. ELSE if STORED.txt is not empty:
   for each phone in the excel - check if it already exists in STORED.txt.

The problem with this approach, is that after many runs, the STORED.txt file already has millions of values, and then a new excel file entered with 100,000 values would have to run over (100,000*millions) of iterations, which makes for an enormous runtime.

I'm wondering if there's a better approach to this issue, not going through O(S*E) complexity (where S are the stored phones and E are the new Excel phones). Any ideas?

BTW, when reading the text file, I'm first storing all the values into a java ArrayList(O(S) time) and only then checking for each phone in the excel if it exists in the ArrayList, using the java ArrayList.contains(value) method. I wonder if it's an efficient way, or maybe there's a way to do it which would be less time-consuming.

Any suggestions would be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: you can create a database table let say in mysql create table contacts with mobile_number, date_inserted, mobile number to be unique key, make the java class to write to it and on duplicate ignore. You can then select from the contacts for the desired dates and give the result from the select statement to your brother. You can even do it without the java class by using LOAD DATA INFILE with MYSL which reads from a csv file, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html Just an idea :)

Comment: another approach would be to load the data from the file into a HashSet, instead of using the ArrayList. Afterwards, HashSet.contains(value) will be fast.

Comment: Is this to support spam?  Just kidding (mostly).

Comment: @justMe why would an SQL approach be faster? wouldn't i still run a query for each excel value, and each query runs over the whole table. still O(S*E), isn't it?

Comment: @qwertyman - Hmm interesting, I'll try that. Just out of curiosity, why are HashSets faster than ArrayLists?

Comment: pure Excel: create master workbook where entries of new files are added.  In separate sheet extract unique values.  Use `COUNTIF()` to determine how many times the phone number has been seen.  In each new Excel file add formula to `VLOOKUP()` the phone number in the master.  If the count > 1 then the phone number was already in an earlier file.

Comment: @E.Mich With a database you can set up an index to make the query faster. It doesn't have to read through the entire table. Its performance will be significantly faster than a text file which by nature will be unsorted.

Comment: BTW, a database is the right tool for this job. While excel can indeed handle what you are trying to do, it wasn't really designed for it. It is kinda like using a hammer to drive a screw. If you get a big enough hammer it will work, but eventually something is going to break.

Comment: @E.Mich HashSets are designed to be fast for lookup. In principle they work like this: every time a new item is inserted into the HashSet, its hashcode (an integer) is calculated, and then the item is stored at a location which depends on that hashcode. When retrieving an item, again its hashcode is calculated, and its potential location is quickly accessible based on that value. You can find details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: The sql approach will be better because it is designed to do this kind of jobs, mysql is free and the approach I mentioned you could just read from a csv file and load the data, give it  try. remember to put an index on date for the select statement after :)